# How to make bluetooth to work on my hp laptop

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, bluetooth

Since last year I have been posting questions on this topic but never got any success.
I have an HP r-201tx laptop on which I have installed Ubuntu 14.04, everything seems to work fine except the bluetooth. The bluetooth is of realtek 8723be type.
My wifi is working perfectly. But ever since i have installed ubuntu on my laptop bluetooth never worked. As mentioned earlier I have been posting questions on this topic but nobody was ever to fix my issue. Please help me to solve this issue.

Output of lspci is:

```
manish@manish-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
0a:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.
```

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of hciconfig -a :

```
manish@manish-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 34:68:95:42:45:9E  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:564 acl:0 sco:0 events:29 errors:0
    TX bytes:358 acl:0 sco:0 commands:29 errors:0
```

If you think this issue can't be solved for my version of ubuntu, shall I install ubuntu 16.04(LTS) for the bluetooth to work on my laptop.

```
manish@manish-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
manish@manish-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.428041] usb 3-1.4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   14.640625] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   14.640651] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.640656] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.640660] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.640668] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.929133] init: bluetooth-touch main process (809) terminated with status 127
[   17.959773] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.959778] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.959785] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.965852] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.965867] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.965883] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
manish@manish-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ls -l /var/lib/bluetooth
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  4  2015 34:68:95:42:45:9E
```

Comment: Please add the outputs of:   
rfkill list  ,   
dmesg | grep -i blue    ,   
 and    
ls  -l /var/lib/bluetooth

Comment: What bluetooth devices are you trying to get working -- what models.  If a mouse, maybe the power indicator in the title bar is interfering -- if it reports on a mouse battery likely the problem (see bug 1098959).

Comment: I am trying to connect my smartphone to my laptop. Nokia XL. No the power indicator in the title bar is not interfering

Answer (score 0):

Your bluetooth hardware is seen, and is not hard blocked (like with a switch), but it is soft blocked.  Run

```
rfkill unblock all
```

and see if the soft block is removed.  If no, try sudo rfkill unblock all.  With the soft block removed, you should be able to run the Settings (Gear in launcher) bluetooth setup, see your bluetooth devices, add a device if necessary, and pair.  Your paired device should appear in the /var/lib/bluetooth/34:68:95:42:45:9E directory, either as a directory (bluez5) or in a file bluez4.
  Another thing to check is the bluetooth notification in the title bar -- it may be in the "off" state, even if bluetooth is "on" in the settings window -- turn it on if necessary.

The bluez5 in 16.04 will be better than the bluez4 (maybe what you're running), but last resort, try another device -- some just wont work.

Comment: i followed all the steps you told me to but still no luck in getting it to work